# In rails, how to mix in a module on both a model and other models that have a belongs_to relationship to it?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have the following module:

```
module PriceItem
  def price_item(mdl, code, opts = {})
     gs_collector.do_something()
  end
end
```

This is mixed into some models in my Rails 3.2 app that have a `belongs_to :gs_collector` relationship.  It works fine.

I would also like to mix this module into the GsCollector model.  But that's where I run into trouble, because if I change `gs_collector` to `self` in the above example, it will no longer work in the other models I've mixed it into.

How can I use this in both `GsCollector`, and the models that have the `belongs_to :gs_collector`?

Comment: IMO a module should be more generic; you've basically written an instance method, not a module function. You might want to consider something like `priceable :gs_collector` which would add a function to the model, and also add a function to GsCollector. (I'm not super-clear on your usecase though.)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with your example. I'm trying to avoid duplicating the price_item method in all the models....  There's likely a better way than what I'm trying to do. My research seemed to show that the best way to share functionality across models was by using a module.

Comment: It generally is, but if you're adding functionality when how it works is different, you'd need to do it in a different way-a way that doesn't depend on how it works in a single class (type).

Comment: @Dave, I ended up creating an instance method on the GsCollector model, based on your advice.  If you put in that suggestion as an answer below, I'd be happy to accept. :)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this is the best, but should consider

```
module PriceItem
  def price_item(mdl, code, opts = {})
     if (gs_collector)
        gs_collector.do_something()
     else
        self.do_something()
     end
  end
end
```